# KVM switch DP in to HDMI out not working

Tags: hdmi, displayport, kvm-switch, docking-station

I have recently bought the the AV Access iDock C10 for what I hoped to be the perfect solution for my problem.

I want to be able to easily switch between my home Windows desktop and Windows work laptop, using the same mouse (optionally some other USB devices), keyboard, and two monitors (in extended settings), while also powering my laptop. Ideally, I should only need to plug in one cable (at the moment USB-C) in my laptop to be able to use it, as I often move it.

In theory the AV Access iDock C10 does this. In practice it works for my laptop, but for my desktop it only works partially. For my desktop, the switch uses one HDMI input and one DP input, which both come from my RTX 2060, and transfers the signals through two HDMI output ports to my two monitors (both Acer KG241QPbiip). However, I only get the HDMI in to HDMI out signal to work, not the DP in to HDMI out signal. My monitor appears to be a bit confused, saying first to look at its HDMI port (which is the one it should use), then to its DP port, then again to its HDMI port, and then it just says no signal and stays black.

The monitor does appear to be detected in my settings. I tried switching between duplicating and extending the screens. I tried lowering resolutions. I tried closing auto-detect on my monitor and forcing it to look at its HDMI input port. I tried different cables. Nothing seems to work. The DP connection works directly from my dekstop to my monitor, so that is also not the issue. It seems very unfortunate that the switch does not simply come with two HDMI input ports instead...

I contacted AV Access support but they only ask me (in really bad English) to try out very basic stuff that I have already tried so I'm not expecting them to be able to resolve my issue.

Does anybody know what might be the solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: DisplayPort has one potential drawback - the PnP never worked well. Quite often I had to connect monitor before powering on the computer for the monitor to be detected. From your description I can't tell if your home PC is on all the time? Try reversing the order: turn on Idock to Home PC, power up Home PC, then connect work laptop to iDock, then switch iDock to laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the order of connecting but unfortunately without success.

I'm also unsure what is meant by using an active DP>HDMI adapter. My connection is DP OUT from PC --> DP IN from KVM switch --> HDMI OUT from KVM switch --> HDMI IN from monitor. I would not know where to put a DP --> HDMI adapter in between?

I now tried a different monitor, and the DP --> HDMI signal did work this time. Thus, it seems an issue specific to my Acer monitor. I really hope to find an explanation/solution to this, as I would like to continue working with 2 of the same monitors.

Comment: Ahh ok after looking at the device, you don't have any DP outputs, and the DP input should be mapped to HDMI Out 1. sure. go ahead and disregard my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

Changing the refresh rate of the screen that receives the HDMI signal originating from the DP output, from 144 Hz to 120 Hz, did the trick.